# Security - jQuery attack of some sort?

Tags: jquery, security

In reading my error logs on a roofing site/app I recently did. I occasionally see the following:

```
http://example.com/Scripts/jquery/)c/=m*2;h!=
```

What is this person, by altering the url like so, trying to accomplish? Any ideas? I was puzzled as he/she is targeting my jquery scripts folder?

Answer (score 1):

They devided `c` with `m*2` and assigned the value to `c`, then made sure `h` is not nothing:

```
c/=m*2;h!=
```

In other words: he did everything. The *ultimate* everything!

---

Or maybe the cat sat on the keyboard and produced a random glob of characters. Cats are *very* good at that.

---

I'm just kidding. ♥

---

**Important bit:** If anything, this "attack" has nothing to do with jQuery. Maybe they tried to make the web server error, somehow? Which they did, but I doubt it could do any damage. So, it's not really a threat.

Comment: Thx for your input. Target was jquery folder that's why I mentioned jquery in case I was unaware of a jquery issue of somekind

Comment: jQuery is purely client-side. So, there's no way they could do any damage even if they "exploited" jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

> What is this person, by altering the url like so, trying to accomplish?

What he was trying to accomplish is **unknown**. While what he gained with it is known: **nothing**

Comment: @Bryant It would be nice if you redacted or censored that IP.

Comment: Thx for your input. I'm curious though as if there is nothing to gain, I'm wondering why this happens in varying frequency every few months on this and other sites/apps on my server...? I catch the IP coming from such request on errors and see it's East of Richmond Virginia...72.84.93.***....Just curious what the deal is and if I'm overlooking some security vulnerability.

Comment: I don't know why it got down-voted. Maybe because it's a bit vague and you said you don't know what the person was trying to accomplish--since that was the question, but other than that I don't see why anyone'd do it. +1s it because of the injustice.